# Is there any way to shorten a query that has a large amount of fields?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a table that has 42 fields. However most of them a roughly similar. I have 20 fields that are named `a01` to `a20`, and another 20 that are named `b01` to `b20`. The other 2 are the PK and an FK.

Is there any way to shorten an `INSERT` query? Right now, because of the PK, I have to specify which columns I am using, Eg:

```
INSERT INTO Table01 (col_FK, a01, b01, a02, b02.....(etc)
```

However, the real trouble I am having is my `SELECT` query. My query basically allows a user to search one or more fields, and have NULL as a comparison, should a field be left empty.

```
SELECT * FROM Table01 WHERE
  (@col_FK IS NULL OR col_FK LIKE @col_FK)
  AND (@a01 IS NULL OR a01 LIKE @a01)
  AND (@b01 IS NULL OR b01 LIKE @b01)
  etc...
```

So for example, if I only entered something in to `a01`, and left the rest empty, the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table01 WHERE
  (NULL IS NULL OR col_FK LIKE NULL)
  AND ('text' IS NULL OR a01 LIKE 'text')
  AND (NULL IS NULL OR b01 LIKE NULL)
  etc...
```

I *really* don't want to have to do that for all 40 fields, so is there any way I could possibly make it shorter?

**Note:** the factoring above (`@a01`, `@b01`) is done in c# so I can pass in parameters to the query.

Comment: How do you know wich field the user wants to search for? Or it's just a "type something and see if it appears in any of the fields" query?

Comment: @Josh what happens is if I search for column `a01` for example, the rest of the query would be compared to `NULL`. For example it would be something like: `SELECT * FROM Table01 WHERE (NULL IS NULL OR col_FK LIKE NULL) AND ('text' IS NULL OR a01 LIKE 'text') etc..`

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but my question is how do you fill or pass `@a01`? Do you have 40 textboxes/inputs? I'm trying to get to the point that, if the query is run from C#, you can dinamically create the string of the query with only the values you want to compare, but I need to know where do the values come from to see if it's possible.

Comment: @Josh ah, sorry. No it's passed into a model and read from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd specify the columns in the `INSERT` statement. That gives you a better chance that your statement will still "work" if new columns are added to the table. And your statement won't be effected if (ack!) the columns in the table are reordered.

As far as making the SELECT statement shorter... that's a matter of having a single *static* SQL statement, vs. multiple variations of a SQL statement. For databases other than MySQL (like Oracle or SQL Server, my personal preference is to use a single static SQL statement with bind placeholders. Then, I have just one SQL statement that needs to be tuned, it stays in the pool and gets reused, not a dozen or more different variations.

I opt for dynamic SQL when I've got an `col IN (?,?,?)`, with a variable number of values in the list. Then it's a matter of how many bind placeholders, and how many corresponding bind parameters.

I'd also opt for dynamic SQL (multiple variants) when it gets me better query plans, that is, it gets a better execution time with fewer resources. That would be just a matter of some code to append `AND a17 LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')` to the SQL text, and corresponding code for the bind. Again, I'd only bother with doing that if it got me a performance boost.

I wouldn't "shorten" any SQL statements just for the sake of "shorter" SQL statements. That doesn't make sense to me, because I'd rather be herding a smaller herd of statements, even if some of those statements are huge. (In terms of managing the bucket of statements, one large statement is actually a easier to manage than a boatload of smaller statements that are all similar to each other.

Comment: I was reviewing the answer I gave; perhaps I didn't really answer the question OP was asking... is there a way to make a static SQL statement shorter, that is, have the statement do the *same* thing but that doesn't require each individual column to be referenced, or each bind value to supplied twice. I didn't really supply the answer to that question ("**no, it's not possible, every column has to be referenced**"). The rest of my response presumes that answer.